# Is there any code for disposble email block in the Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, wordpress

I am getting a lot of fakes registration and form submission on WordPress and Magento 1.9. Please suggest some ideas.

Thank you

Comment: For the magento you can use recaptcha.

Answer (score 0):

I too were getting a lot of Russian "customers".   First I use a plugin called GeoLock which can block unwanted countries.   I enabled Captcha to eliminate bots.   I disabled any sign up without full name address and phone #.  I disabled Newsletter sign up.  I enabled Email verification.  After all this I still get some fakes which I review and if the Email is not verified, I delete them manually.

Comment: I already have Captcha. I will try your plugin now.